# What is the sum of all the natural numbers between $500$ and $1000$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic, divisibility

What is the sum of all the natural numbers between $500$ and $1000$ (extremes included) that are multiples of $2$ but not of $7$?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Working on it using http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/513846/find-the-sum-of-all-the-integers-between-1-and-1000-which-are-divisible-by-7 and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9259/find-the-sum-of-all-the-multiples-of-3-or-5-below-1000 am I on the right path?

Comment: Looks like a good one to emulate, yes. How about: Find the sum of all even numbers in the given range. Find the sum of all multiples of 14 in the given range. Subtract.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**In general**, the sum of an arithmetic progression is $$S_n = \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i=\frac{n}{2}(a_1+a_n)$$

So, the **sum of all even numbers** in your interval

$$ = \frac{251}{2}(500+1000)$$

And the **sum of all multiples of $14$** in your interval
$$ = \frac{36}{2}(504+994)$$

Subtracting these two answers will give you the result you are looking for.

Comment: 188250 - 26964 = 161286 @Cm7F7Bb got 149536

Comment: I've checked mine in python, it's correct.

Comment: I get it! Thanks for answer and explanations.

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=0}^{250}(500+2i)-\sum_{i=0}^{35}(504+14i)
&=251\cdot500+2\sum_{i=0}^{250}i-36\cdot504-14\sum_{i=0}^{35}i\\
&=251\cdot500+2\biggl[\frac{251(0+250)}2\biggr]-36\cdot504-14\biggl[\frac{36(0+35)}2\biggr]\\
&=161286
\end{align*}
using the arithmetic progression formula (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression)).

Comment: +1 for the correction and progression formula. The acceptance belongs to @Daniel Thanks both!

Answer (score 0):

**hint1:** for divisibility by 2 find the sum of arithmetic numbers of distance2

**hint2**: Numbers divisible of 7 are either multiples of 14 or divisible by 14 when added 7, so try to subtract sequence of difference 14 from your sum

Answer (score 0):

Heres a code solution using a C# console application:

```
// hold all numbers to be summed 

List<int> multiplesOfTwoCollection = new List<int>();<br>

// count numbers 

for (int naturalNumber = 500; naturalNumber <= 1000; naturalNumber++)

{ if (naturalNumber % 2 == 0) { multiplesOfTwoCollection.Add(naturalNumber); }

// log contents

 Console.WriteLine("natural number:{0}", naturalNumber); }

// multiples of 7

int sumOfInts = 0;
foreach (var item in multiplesOfTwoCollection)
 if (item % 7 == 0) { Console.WriteLine("multiple of 7:{0}", item);
     } else { sumOfInts += item; }

Console.WriteLine("sum of numbers between 500 and 1000 that are multiples of 2 not 7:{0}", sumOfInts);
```

**Returns**

161286

Comment: You should at least format your post so that it is more readable, please.

Comment: yes i apologize, it was awful wasnt it. i have reformatted.